# perform a $set and a $rename in an update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following doc

{
"value": 5
}

i want the update to lead to the following:

{
"value_old": 5,
"value": 3
}

I am trying to achieve this using the following update query

```
      {
        $rename: {"value": "value_old"}
      },
      { $set :{
        "value": (wtv new value was sent to the function) 3
      }
```

This code doesn't seem to be working....
I do not want to perform two separate update queries

I've tried aggregation and an $out at the end of it but that leads to the deletion of the entire collection, and I only want to update an individual document.

The reason I am doing this is because I need the operation to be atomic. I was just reading up on db.eval() and it seems promising as it locks the db from reads and writes. Does anyone know how to use db.eval() to perform 2 updates?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MongoClient, you can handle both in async fashion. For example:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

function updateDB (newVal) {
  return MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URL)
    .then( (database) => {
      return Promise.all([
        database.collection('yourCollection').update({id: 123}, {$rename: {'value': 'value_old'}}),
        database.collection('yourCollection').update({
            $set: {'value': newVal}
        })
      ])
      .then(() => {
        database.close(true);
      })
      .then(() => {
        return `new value: ${newVal} has been updated in : ${whatever}`;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        database.close(true);
        throw err;
      });
    })
}
```

This is what I have done and should be safe to execute many operations and close the db also, only when all have completed.

Comment: This could be dangerous because there's no guarantee on the ordering of the two operations. You might end up with the $set is done before the $rename.